# How to host a firebase server

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, firebase

I have a landing page with a "Pay with Mercado Pago" button, and it works perfectly on localhost. But how to host using this server on Firebase? It's a React App and I deployed the build. Do I send server.js to the hosting as is?

[image]

On the computer I start the server with "node server.js" and then start the clientview with "npm run dev"

Client:

```
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { initMercadoPago, Wallet } from "@mercadopago/sdk-react";
import axios from "axios";
import img from "../../assets/Bananita.png";

import "./Product.css";

const Product = () => {
  const [preferenceId, setPreferenceId] = useState(null);

  initMercadoPago("PUBLIC_KEY");

  const createPreference = async () => {
    try {
      const response = await axios.post("http://localhost:8080/create_preference", {
        description: "Test",
        price: 1,
        quantity: 1,
      });

      const { id } = response.data;
      return id;
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  };

  // Execute handleBuy on component load using useEffect
  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchPreference = async () => {
      const id = await createPreference();
      if (id) {
        setPreferenceId(id);
      }
    };

    fetchPreference();
  }, []); // Empty dependency array ensures useEffect runs only once on component mount

  return (
    <div className="card-product-container">
      <div className="card-product">
        <div className="card">
          <img src={img} alt="Product Image" />
          <h3>Bananita contenta</h3>
          <p className="price">100 $</p>
      
       
          {preferenceId && <Wallet initialization={{ preferenceId }} />}
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Product;
```

server.js:

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const cors = require("cors");
const mercadopago = require("mercadopago");

app.use(express.json());
app.use(cors());

mercadopago.configure({
  access_token: "ACCESS_TOKEN",
});

app.get("/", function (req, res) {
  res.send("el servidor de mercado pago funciona! :)");
});

app.post("/create_preference", (req, res) => {
  let preference = {
    items: [
      {
        title: req.body.description,
        unit_price: Number(req.body.price),
        quantity: Number(req.body.quantity),
      },
    ],
    back_urls: {
      success: "http://localhost:5173",
      failure: "http://localhost:5173",
      pending: "",
    },
    auto_return: "approved",
  };

  mercadopago.preferences
    .create(preference)
    .then(function (response) {
      res.json({
        id: response.body.id,
      });
    })
    .catch(function (error) {
      console.log(error);
    });
});

app.listen(8080, () => {
  console.log("the server is now running on port 8080");
})
```

How to host this react app and the pay with Mercado Pago button still working?